# Display another column where the conditions are determined in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| address | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tokyo | 124.4423 | 95.223 |
| Budapest | 156.2442 | 78.112 |
| Perth | 124.9234 | 20.490 |

I have an example of a data frame as seen above (please don't mind the accuracy); address is string, latitude and longitude are floats. I would like to to display the address where the condition meets both latitude and longitude.

Example:

```
Latitude = 156.2442
Longitude = 78.112
```

Therefore I want to display/print the corresponding column address, which would be "Budapest".

Comment: pandas is not base Python; please tag pandas questions [tag:pandas]. Also, it's a bad idea to say *"please don't mind the accuracy"*, because **there is a very well-known problem with exactness when storing and comparing floats**. It's quite possible that a pandas dataframe internally stores e.g. longitude as 78.1117 but displays it as 78.112. i.e the display precision and format can be lower than what is stored internally. This can break your code unless you cater to it with inexact FP comparisons, or always know the internal precision of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can take is:

```
lat = 156.2442 # insert your latitude
long = 78.112 # insert your longtitude
print(df[(df['latitude']==lat) & (df['longitude'] == long)]['address'])
```

which prints:

```
1    Budapest
Name: address, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas filtering:

```
df[(df.latitude=='156.2442') & (df.longitude == '78.112')]['address']
```

Comment: does it also work if i put variable for latitude and longitude respectively?
Example : 

lat = 156.2442
long = 78.112

df[(df.latitude==lat) & (df.longitude =long)]['address']

Comment: It will work but you should notice that the datatypes should be the same. for example if the datatype of that number is a string u should define lat and long as strings. and if they are float numbers you should define them as float type.

Comment: Your code like that will not work. You need an extra ```=```,  ```(df.longitude == '78.112')]['address']```

Comment: Yeah thanks I added the "=" and edited the answer, it was obvious though